# Magento 2 composer "module-wishlist" error

Tags: magento2, module, upgrade, composer, sample-data

I'm trying to update my magento version to 2.2 (from 2.1.7) but had a "Content Dependency" error, but have narrowed down the issue a module, the "module-wishlist-sample-data" magento module.

When I try to update composer I get the following error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - magento/module-wishlist-sample-data 100.1.1 requires magento/module-wishlist 100.1.* -> satisfiable by magento/module-wishlist[100.1.4, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.1.2, 100.1.3, 100.1.5, 100.1.6].
    - magento/module-wishlist-sample-data 100.1.0-rc1 requires magento/module-wishlist 100.1.* -> satisfiable by magento/module-wishlist[100.1.4, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.1.2, 100.1.3, 100.1.5, 100.1.6].
    - magento/module-wishlist-sample-data 100.1.0-rc2 requires magento/module-wishlist 100.1.* -> satisfiable by magento/module-wishlist[100.1.4, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.1.2, 100.1.3, 100.1.5, 100.1.6].
    - magento/module-wishlist-sample-data 100.1.0-rc3 requires magento/module-wishlist 100.1.* -> satisfiable by magento/module-wishlist[100.1.4, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.1.2, 100.1.3, 100.1.5, 100.1.6].
    - magento/module-wishlist-sample-data 100.1.0 requires magento/module-wishlist 100.1.* -> satisfiable by magento/module-wishlist[100.1.4, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.1.2, 100.1.3, 100.1.5, 100.1.6].
    - magento/module-wishlist-sample-data 100.1.1 requires magento/module-wishlist 100.1.* -> satisfiable by magento/module-wishlist[100.1.4, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.1.2, 100.1.3, 100.1.5, 100.1.6].
    - Can only install one of: magento/module-wishlist[101.0.0, 100.1.4].
    - Can only install one of: magento/module-wishlist[101.0.0, 100.1.0-rc1].
    - Can only install one of: magento/module-wishlist[101.0.0, 100.1.0-rc2].
    - Can only install one of: magento/module-wishlist[101.0.0, 100.1.0-rc3].
    - Can only install one of: magento/module-wishlist[101.0.0, 100.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: magento/module-wishlist[101.0.0, 100.1.1].
    - Can only install one of: magento/module-wishlist[101.0.0, 100.1.2].
    - Can only install one of: magento/module-wishlist[101.0.0, 100.1.3].
    - Can only install one of: magento/module-wishlist[101.0.0, 100.1.4].
    - Can only install one of: magento/module-wishlist[101.0.0, 100.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: magento/module-wishlist[101.0.0, 100.1.6].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.2.0 requires magento/module-wishlist 101.0.0 -> satisfiable by magento/module-wishlist[101.0.0].
    - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.2.0 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.2.0].
    - Installation request for magento/module-wishlist-sample-data 100.1.* -> satisfiable by magento/module-wishlist-sample-data[100.1.1, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0].
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

what you should do is:

1. Remove from your composer.json all the sample data modules.
2. Run composer update.
3. Run "php -f bin/magento sampledata:deploy" this will add the latest sample data modules to your composer.json based on your M2 version.

That should be enough.

Comment: Thanks! What is the correct way to remove all the sample data from composer.json?

Comment: Edit the composer.json using your prefered text editor, just remove the lines like "magento/module- * -sample-data".
Last option I think is to set every sample data to * (example "magento/module-catalog-sample-data": " * "), this will update it to the latest possible version validating it's valid for all the rest of the modules

Comment: Nice to hear that! please do not forget to mark this question as solved. Kind regards

Comment: Thanks a lot 
We can use command to remove sampledat : php bin/magento sampledata:remove

Comment: @MatiasHidalgo After i followed your instruction i getting an error like:: https://snag.gy/fP90NA.jpg 
 could you kindly help me to get out this issue? my composer.json file is :: https://justpaste.it/2km8p

Answer (score 2):

We could also uninstall the sample modules by command line.

`php bin/magento module:uninstall Sample_Module_Data`

It is more secure than edit the composer.json directly, it will auto puts the store in maintenance mode. And has some smart option to set, like `--remove-data`.

More details you could see the official guide [Uninstall modules](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-uninstall-mods.html#instgde-cli-uninst-mod-uninst).

After uninstall, you could reinstall the latest sample data or just leave it.

`php bin/magento sampledata:deploy`